# Как преобразовать URL или String в File?

Tags: java, файлы, url

Необходимо передать из переменной типа `URL` ссылку на файл в переменную типа `File`. Как вариант, можно и `String` в `File`.
Весь интернет перерыл - ничего подходящего не нашёл. Среда разработки никаких подходящих методов не подсказала.
Из `File` в `String` всё конвертируется отлично, а вот наоборот - нет. Как это реализовать?

Comment: вы хотите сделать объект типа File, который описывает файл по указанному URL? что дальше будет с файлом?

Comment: Да, имеется, скажем, `URL source` с записью `"c://papka/file.html"`, также рядом `File fl`, собственно в который и нужно передать ссылку из source. Дальше файл будет копироваться с помощью java.io.FileOutputStream и import java.io.FileInputStream

Comment: вы понимаете, что URL может указывать не только на файл? к тому же указанный вами URL не верный - вы получите **MalformedURLException**

Comment: с ошибками компилятора я разберусь сам. Просто ответьте, есть ли какой то метод, или просто способ передать значение из URL в File? Если есть, то какой? И этот URL я написал от руки, на самом деле он получается другим способом, и он действителен

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(new File("любая строка типа String"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться методом [toURI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#toURI()) класса `URL`:

```
URL url = ...
try
{
    File file = new File(url.toURI());
}
catch (URISyntaxException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Ещё можно попробовать через метод [getPath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getPath()):

```
URL url = ...
File file = new File(url.getPath());
```

Comment: при попытке передать(вторая строчка) сказал `Unhandled exception type URISyntaxException`

Comment: @tovarish потому что код должен быть в `try-catch`. Или метод должен пробрасывать это исключение. Я понадеялся, что обработка исключений - это не проблема.

Comment: хах, я совсем про это и забыл. Сейчас попробую)

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку **URL** может указывать не только на файл в локальной файловой системе, то преобразовать его в **File** автоматически нельзя.

Один вариант просто создать поток из этого **URL** и читать из него.

```
URL u = ...;
byte buffer[] = new byte[1000];

InputStream is = u.openStream();
is.read(buffer);
```

Второй вариант - это анализ полученного **URL** и извлечение из него пути к файлу.

```
URL u = ...;
if(u.getProtocol().equals("file")) {
    System.out.println(u.getFile());
}
```